Query information from one column, but separate into different columns
I have a SQL query that needs to pull information from a table that looks like this.  I need each entry under RollupCatCd (CRP,DIV,GRP,REG) to be its own column alongside JobCd, and then the corresponding RollupCd to show underneath it.  Right now I pull everything else I need together and then I vlookup this information into the sheet after creating a pivot table to get it into the format I need.  this is a very tedious process.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below is the query I have built.  Thanks in advance.
SELECT 
    JobCd,
    RollupCatCd,
    RollupCd, 
    CurrentYN
FROM [Gorilla].[dbo].[jobCtrl_Rollup]
WHERE CurrentYN = '1'

Raw Data



JobCd
RollupCatCd
RollupCd




100
GRP
7


100
REG
7


155
CRP
1


155
DIV
2


155
GRP
2


155
REG
2


156
CRP
1


156
DIV
2


156
GRP
2


156
REG
2


160
CRP
1


160
DIV
2


160
GRP
2


160
REG
2



Preferred Result



JobCd
CRP
DIV
GRP
REG




100

7
7



155
1
2
2
2


156
1
2
2
2


160
1
2
2
2




This question is similar to: Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You're looking for a Conditional Aggregation.
PIVOTS are fine, but a Conditional Aggregation offers a bit more flexibility.
Select JobCd
      ,CRP = max( case when RollupCatCd = 'CRP' then RollupCd end )
      ,DIV = max( case when RollupCatCd = 'DIV' then RollupCd end )
      ,GRP = max( case when RollupCatCd = 'GRP' then RollupCd end )
      ,REG = max( case when RollupCatCd = 'REG' then RollupCd end )
 From  [Gorilla].[dbo].[jobCtrl_Rollup]
 WHERE CurrentYN = '1'
 Group By JobCd


This works beautifully by itself, thank you very much!!!  When I incorporate this into a bigger query where I am joining 6 tables I get a Column ' ' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  I am working through all that now to see if I can figure it out.

@ChrisKessler every column in an aggregate query HAS to be either an aggregate like min(), max(), sum() OR  in the GROUP BY

Thanks for that.  I was slowly realizing that as I added each column to the GROUP BY and the message moved to the next column.  LOL.  this is awesome, thank you so much.

@ChrisKessler Way to work the problem!

Absolutely.  Fixed this, now I am onto the next challenge with this query & report.

Should I create a new question if I have a similar issue to this where I am trying to move contacts from multiple rows into separate columns?  JobCd can have multiple ContactCd entires, and SQL creates a new JobCd row for each.  I am trying to move the ContactCd entries into columns for FNAME1, LNAME1, FNAME2, LNAME2, FNAME3, LNAME3.  I have managed to move them to the columns, but they are still on separate rows.

@ChrisKessler A new question with sample data would be best.   Off the top of my head, you may be looking for row_number() over (...)

@ChrisKessler  Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78257568/parsing-first-name-and-last-name/78257740#78257740

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Oh, good. I needed more practice using the PIVOT keyword:
SELECT JobCd, GRP, REG, CRP, DIV
FROM
(
    SELECT JobCd, RollupCatCd, RollupCd  
    FROM jobCtrl_Rollup
    WHERE CurrentYN = '1'
) d
PIVOT
(
    MAX(RollupCd)
    FOR RollupCatCd
    IN ( GRP, REG, CRP, DIV )
) p
ORDER BY JobCd;

See it work here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/oZcgaY1I

This works because we know the exact columns we need. This is MUCH more complicated if we don't know before looking at the data.

The SELECT *  will cause issues if there are other columns in the source table.   SELECT JobCd, RollupCatCd, RollupCd  would be safer.

@JohnCappelletti Good point.

The PIVOT returned the correct Column Headings, but I still had a separate row for each.    So Columns were JobCd, GRP, REG, CRP, DIV but each of those columns also had its own row.  I am working through incorporating this into my bigger query as well to see how it works.  Thank you very much.

@ChrisKessler Check the fiddle link. If you've done it right, that doesn't happen.

I will continue to mess with it.  I appreciate the help
